# Why is merge sort complexity considered O(n log n), this is not the full complexity?

Tags: sorting, big-o, mergesort

I follow that merge sort is called in the worst case scenario n log n, but what about the complexity of actually merging the split parameter array each call.

Should merge sort actually be n log n * sorting time mean or something.

Comment: no merge sort is actually `n*log(n)` in each call of merging it takes `O(n)` time and `O(n)` extra space, and it's best when we have to sort really large file.

Answer (score 2):

On a "traditional" merge sort, each pass through the data doubles the size of the sorted subsections. After the first pass, the file will be sorted into sections of length two. After the second pass, length four. Then eight, sixteen, etc. up to the size of the file.

It's necessary to keep doubling the size of the sorted sections until there's one section comprising the whole file. It will take lg(N) doublings of the section size to reach the file size, and each pass of the data will take time proportional to the number of records.

Comment: exactly, then each pass of the data will take time proportional to the number of records. This is not accounted for

Comment: @CanisLupus - Each pass time complexity is O(n), and for a 2-way bottom up merge sort, there are log2(n) passes, so the total time complexity is O(n log(n)).